# Como mostrar valor do HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

Estou com dificuldade em mostrar (pode ser utilizando um `for`) o valor deste HashMap. Alguém sabe como? O console só mostra esse valor:

> {joao=[Ljava.lang.String;@2b05039f}

Não consigo mostrar o vetor interno, o `String[]`:

```
HashMap<String, String[][]> hm = new HashMap<String,String[][]>();          
            hm.put("joao", new String[][]{
                    {"joao", "joao"}
            } );
```

O que eu quero é representar uma estrutura de dados como essa:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'input1' => 
        array 
          'pattern' => string '[\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{2}[\)]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}'
          'type' => string 'tel'
          'value' => string '+91 98111222333'
  1 => 
    array
      'button1' => 
        array
          'pattern' => string '
          'type' => string 'button'
          'value' => string 'validate'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não ficou claro, mas no seu exemplo aparentemente sempre existe um *pattern*, um *type* e um *value*. Então por que não criar um objeto com esses atributos?

```java
public class Element {
    private String pattern, type, value;

    public Element(String pattern, String type, String value) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // get, set
}
```

E então, ao invés de criar uma estrutura monstruosa de `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<...` você teria um simples map de `Element`. Por exemplo:

```java
// pattern, type, value
Element input = new Element("[\\+]\\d{2}[\\(]\\d{2}[\\)]\\d{4}[\\-]\\d{4}", "tel", "+91 98111222333");
Element button  = new Element("", "button", "validate");

HashMap<String, Element> map = new HashMap(){{
    put("input1", input);
    put("button1", button);
}};
```

Para percorrer esse *map*, pode usar a interface `Entry`:

```java
for(Entry<String, Element> each : map.entrySet()){

  // No caso, a 'key' é a String com o nome do elemento.
  System.out.println("Nome do elemento: " + each.getKey());

  // E o 'value' é o nosso objeto 'Element'.
  Element current = each.getValue();
  System.out.println("Pattern: " + current.getPattern());
  System.out.println("Type: " + current.getType());
  System.out.println("Value: " + current.getValue());
}
```

*ouput*:

> Nome do elemento: input1 
>   Pattern: [+]\d{2}[(]\d{2}[)]\d{4}[-]\d{4}
>   Type: tel
>   Value: +91 98111222333
>
> Nome do elemento: button1
>   Pattern: 
>   Type: button 
>   Value: validate

---

---

<sub><sub>Resposta antes da pergunta ser editada:</sub></sub>

Pode utilizar utilizar o método `toString` de [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html):

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hm.get("joao")));
```

*output*:

> [10, 2015, 10101]

---

Ou então pode percorrer o *array* normalmente:

```java
for(String each : hm.get("joao"))
    System.out.println(each);
```

*output*:

> 10 
>   2015 
>   10101

Comment: Testei no Eclipse e continua com o mesmo erro :(

Comment: atualizei com o codigo atual

Comment: No PHP seria simples criar aquela estrutura, agora no Java tô quebrando a kuka

Comment: System.out.println(hm);

Comment: Ah, agora que vi que você editou a pergunta e mudou a estrutura.

Comment: Pois é, tá hard criar aquela simples estrutura viu :(

Comment: Eu estava editando a minha resposta mas você editou de novo

Comment: Só deixei mais claro :)

Comment: Editei novamente.

Comment: Apaguei a pergunta lá. Muito boa sua resposta.

Comment: E se na minha página tiver 100 inputs? Vou precisar instanciar 100x?

Comment: Mas `input1` é somente a chave para encontrar o objeto do *map*, pode ser qualquer nome alí. Se sua página tiver 100 inputs, pode instanciar um único e fazer um loop para adicioná-lo 100 vezes no *map*. É preciso mesmo 100 elementos dentro da coleção? Não seria mais viável agrupar elementos com propriedades idênticas? Enfim, aí já é outra pergunta.

Comment: Verdade. Voce está certo. Obrigado